# Do a running total of a field with the exception of the description contains a certain text string

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to run this report where it does a running total with the exception if the "description" field contains "FUND TRANSFER" I have the group suppressed int he report itself, but it still goes into the running total.

Here is a screenshot of the report screen and a brief explaination .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your running total under "Evaluate" change it from "For each record" to "Use a formula" and enter a formula along these lines:

`{Record.Description}<>"FUND TRANSFER"`

Now the running total will only sum records that are not of that type.